# How to remove extra white space between words inside a character vector using?

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have a character vector like

```
"Hi,  this is a   good  time to   start working   together.".
```

I just want to have

```
" Hi, this is a good time to start working together."
```

Only one white space between two words. How should I do this in R?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`gsub` is your friend:

```
test <- "Hi,  this is a   good  time to   start working   together."
gsub("\\s+"," ",test)
#[1] "Hi, this is a good time to start working together."
```

`\\s+` will match any space character (space, tab etc), or repeats of space characters, and will replace it with a single space `" "`.

Comment: I was using `"\\s"` in the second argument instead of `" "`, thanks!

Comment: But using `"\\s"` in the second argument `" "` positing removes all the spaces and bring all the letters together.

Comment: @thelatemail Can you suggest a faster code than this?

Answer (score 30):

Another option is the squish function from the stringr library

```
library(stringr)
string <- "Hi,  this is a   good  time to   start working   together."
str_squish(string)
#[1] ""Hi, this is a good time to start working together.""
```

Comment: This is easier than other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Since the title of the question is "remove the extra whitespace **between words**", *without touching the leading and trailing whitespaces*, the answer is (assuming the "words" are non-whitespace character chunks)

```r
gsub("(\\S)\\s{2,}(?=\\S)", "\\1 ", text, perl=TRUE)
stringr::str_replace_all(text, "(\\S)\\s{2,}(?=\\S)", "\\1 ")
## Or, if the whitespace to leep is  the last whitespace in those matched
gsub("(\\S)(\\s){2,}(?=\\S)", "\\1\\2", text, perl=TRUE)
stringr::str_replace_all(text, "(\\S)(\\s){2,}(?=\\S)", "\\1\\2")
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/bFJceB/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/bFJceB/3) and [this R demo](https://ideone.com/ikApOL).

**Regex details**:

- `(\S)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): a non-whitespace char
- `\s{2,}` - two or more whitespace chars (in Regex #2, it is wrapped with parentheses to form a capturing group with ID 2 (`\2`))
- `(?=\S)` - a positive lookahead that requires a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

The package [`textclean`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textclean/textclean.pdf) has many useful tools for processing text. `replace_white` would be useful here:

```
v <- "Hi,  this is a   good  time to   start working   together."

textclean::replace_white(v)
# [1] "Hi, this is a good time to start working together."
```