# Replace all double spaces with single spaces in string

Tags: regex, r, whitespace, gsub

I would like to reduce all spaces longer than a single space in a string to a single space.

```
foo(" 1   2    3     4                 5 ")
[1] " 1 2 3 4 5 "
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove extra white space between words inside a character vector using R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128327/how-to-remove-extra-white-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using-r)

Comment: Good point. I did not see that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would work:

```
gsub(' +',' ',foo)
```

:)

*(edited to take into account Zach's comment)*

Comment: Suggest `"  +"` instead of `"  *"`.  It will do less unnecessary work.