# how to remove double white space at the end of string in R?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, gsub

I'm trying to fix some cells in a tibble. The column of my interest contains strings with white spaces and double white spaces at begin or end.

I saw these posts before asking

- [Merge Multiple spaces to single space; remove trailing/leading spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707647/merge-multiple-spaces-to-single-space-remove-trailing-leading-spaces)
- [How to remove extra white space between words inside a character vector using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128327/how-to-remove-extra-white-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using)
- [How to remove all whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string)
- [How to trim leading and trailing whitespace in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r)

This is a reproducible example of what I'm doing

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars2 = tbl_df(mtcars) %>% 
   mutate(name = rownames(mtcars)) %>%
   mutate(name = gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", name, perl = TRUE)) %>%  
   mutate(name = gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", name)) %>%
   mutate(name = iconv(name, from = "", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT", sub = ""))

head(mtcars2, 3)
```

And the result is

```
# A tibble: 3 × 12
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb          name
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <chr>
1  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4     Mazda RX4
2  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4 Mazda RX4 Wag
3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1    Datsun 710
```

But in my dataset after doing that some double white spaces persist !!

Is there a more general command to remove white spaces at the end of string? Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Where are those whitespaces? Are these regular or some Unicode whitespaces? Try `gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$|(\s)+", "$1", name)`

Comment: "But in my dataset after doing that some double white spaces persist" -- in other words, you don't have a reproducible example yet? There is `trimws`, probably mentioned in your links, though I don't see it in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the `trimws()` function?

```
> trimws('   hello   ')
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/trimws.html

amazing !! I didn't know that and it also considers tabs as whitespace !!

Comment: `mutate(name = gsub("  ", "", name)) %>%` seems to work ... for now :(

Comment: `gsub`ing will remove trailing white spaces, but it will also remove spaces inside the string, which could cause worse problems.