# removing spaces from all column names at once in R using gsub

Tags: r, multiple-columns, gsub, batch-rename

I have a datafile with 57 columns and most of my column names contain space. According to the [Best Practices in Preparing Data Files for Importing into R](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/best-practices-in-preparing-data-files-for-importing-into-r)
blank spaces should be removed. I tried using the `gsub` as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128327/how-to-remove-extra-white-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using) however I do not know how to refer to the column names ?

```
gsub("\\s+","_",mydata)
```

this renames my entire datafile. How can I rename the column names only?

Comment: Try `names(mydata) <- gsub("\\s+","_", names(mydata))`

Comment: @markus your solution works, thanks - quick & easy