# split a row into columns in a data frame in r

Tags: r, string, row

How can I split this column up after exporting?

I need to get each value in a row separated by a space as a separate column.

Currently I have:

```
V1
X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836
X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836
X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836
X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836
```

And this is what I want:

```
V1    V2       V3         V4        V5
X    1111    1324.01    1258.00   5154836
X    1111    1324.01    1258.00   5154836
X    1111    1324.01    1258.00   5154836
X    1111    1324.01    1258.00   5154836
```

I tried:

```
separate(col = V1, into = c("V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), sep = " ")
```

and:

```
SPS_X1 <- SPS_X %>% strsplit(SPS_X," ")
```

but these did not work for what I need.

P.S. my data frame has >5000000 rows

Comment: Try `library(splitstackshape);cSplit(df1, "V1", " ")`

Comment: In base R you could do `SPS_X1 <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(SPS_X$V1, " ")))`

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron for your answer, but this command return 'number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)'

Comment: I shared base file in [link] (https://yadi.sk/d/fwMZm1K2vRZ1Cw)

Answer (score 1):

base on your shared link made this `script`

```
file <- "DD_1.x"

clean_data <- function(string){
  no_blank <- gsub("\\s+"," ", string) # Remove extra blank spaces 
  strsplit(no_blank," ")[[1]] # Split string by spaces, return array
}

l <- readLines(file, n = 200) # Read first 200 lines

data.frame(do.call("rbind",lapply(l,clean_data))) # Makes dataframe
```

Hope this can help you.

[Remove extra blank spaces on R-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128327/how-to-remove-extra-white-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using)

Comment: Thanks, this good work, but return only first row... l <- readLines can't work in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read.table` to *split a row into columns*.

```
read.table(text=x$V1)
#  V1   V2      V3   V4      V5
#1  X 1111 1324.01 1258 5154836
#2  X 1111 1324.01 1258 5154836
#3  X 1111 1324.01 1258 5154836
#4  X 1111 1324.01 1258 5154836
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(V1=c("X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836","X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836"
 ,"X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836","X 1111 1324.01 1258.00 5154836"))
```